# what does git merge - do, is that dash syntax merge specific?

Tags: git

One my colleagues accidentally ran `git merge -` and it seemed to merge the branch they were last on. Fascinating. `git describe -` errors out `fatal: Not a valid object name -`. `git symbolic-ref --short  -` also errors out with `fatal: ref - is not a symbolic ref`.

It's obviously(?) impossible to search for this. Where is this documented, is this merge specific, if not where else could it be used?

Edit: our principal sw engineer pointed out https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout `You may also specify - which is synonymous to @{-1}` so I guess the same happens to `git merge` but a) it's not documented under `git merge` b) `git describe` or `git log` doesn't work with `-` while both work with `@{-1}` c) it's still not clear where else could it be used especially if it's undocumented.

Comment: So, `-` gets resolved to `@{-1}`. Which is essentially a listing from the `git reflog`.

Comment: Possibly [explained by](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt-ltcommitgt82308203): "If no commit is given from the command line, merge the remote-tracking branches that the current branch is configured to use as its upstream."

Comment: @Nayuki I thought of that too, obviously, but it doesn't seem to cover the case. I think the `@{-1}` must be right, which does indeed mean "the previous branch" (which is way cool, I use it a lot).

Comment: @chx Sir, I found a reference to the same [here](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/git/how-to-checkout-the-previous-branch.html)

`git switch -`, `git rebase -` should also work

Comment: OK, that's just super cool! Thanks for asking the question. I'm an instant fan of this feature!

Comment: The fact that it's not documented is (in my opinion at least) a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dash syntax to represent `@{-1}` is implemented in some commands and not others, and its design comes from `cd`, which typically supports a similar feature (switching to the last directory).

It's known upstream that it's not implemented in all commands, and the threshold for implementing it is roughly, "Is it useful in this case to refer to the immediately previous branch in this context?"  Clearly it's useful in checkout, switch, and restore, but nobody thought it was useful in log, so it wasn't implemented.  If you can make a compelling argument for implementing it, patches would be welcome.  The Git list has received patches for this in the past.

The reason it doesn't work everywhere is because it's implemented on a command-by-command basis instead of in the revision parsing machinery, like `@{-1}` is.  Things implemented in the revision parsing machinery (documented in the `gitrevisions(7)` manual page) will be available everywhere.

Comment: Weird. Was there an attempt to implement it in the revision parsing machinery and if yes why was it rejected? Especially if there's code already to expand it into `@{-1}` moving that over to the revparsing machine ought to be trivial...?

Comment: No, there was no such attempt.  The maintainer doesn't see it as a thing which should be universally available in that way, so if you want that behavior, `@{-1}` is the right solution.